# error when converting json date to PHP (m/d/Y)

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to convert from JSON string to PHP a DOB and it works but gives me the wrong DOB.

```
$url = "test.js";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$DOB = date('m/d/Y', preg_replace('/[^\d]/','', $json['Player'][BirthDt])/1000);
```

what get JSONJason is :

```
"BirthDt":"\/Date(-388094400000)\/"
```

in PHP i get this:*04/19/1982* instead of **09/14/1957**

any ideas???

Comment: Calculating it manually, 4/19/1982 is indeed the date represented by that timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is removing the negative sign, so it's becoming a date after the unix epoch (Jan 1st 1970), instead of before. Try something like this:

```
preg_match('/Date\((-?\d+)\)/', $json['Player']['BirthDt'], $matches);
$timestamp = $matches[1];
$DOB = date('m/d/Y', $timestamp / 1000);
```

You can see it working in [the demo](http://viper-7.com/kBrsCm).

Comment: @nickb :quick question, there's one DOB that keeps failing and no idea why. json output is: `"BirthDt":"\/Date(103608000000)\/"` so it should be the same as 04/14/1973 but PHP is showing 1 day before 04/13/1973 instead???

Comment: @nickb - hi.. it was the time zone. i chanegd to GMT and wotks now. sorry for the trouble and thanks!